# How to change the number of undo steps in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way to increase the number of undo steps that Notepad++ can remember? I looked in the options and googled many variations of this question, but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: I'm afraid it is not possible.

Comment: Looks like that, but seems strange.

Comment: Telling just in case you missed that: If you undo some changes and instead of redo, then do a new change, you will loose the previous redo/undo steps. For example: We write `a` then `a` then `a` until we have `aaaaa`. Then we undo 4 times so we go back to `a`. By now, we can still redo the changes with redo (control+y). However if by that point we do a new change like pressing 'b' to get `ab`, we will loose the previous redo/undo actions. You won't be able to go back to `aaaaa` with undo.

Answer (score 0):

Settings>Preferences>Recent Files History>Max Number of Entries. At the time I answered this maximum is 30

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. They want to modify the number of **undo steps**, not the number of files recently opened.